# Rails - Creating and Validating Many-to-Many relationship with the same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

This is probably a really simple question, but I've been searching the web for probably around an hour and I can't really find an answer to my problem. It should be clear by what follows that I am very new to Rails, so my terminology and explanation might be a bit confusing.

Let's say that I were making a social media app on Rails, where one of the models is User. I want to make a many-to-many relationship called "friends", which links two users together. Let's say in this situation I also wanted to make a many-to-many between two users called "enemies".

This is all completely hypothetical, but the idea is the same one that I want to use for something I'm working on.

Because a user can have many friends and enemies, but also *be* many friends and enemies, I would use:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users #this should be the friends association
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users #this should be the enemies association
end
```

Now I'm guessing I can't just do that, because I would have to have two tables both named users_users. So, then I switch to:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many(:users, join_table: 'friends', 
  foreign_key: 'user_id', associate_foreign_key: 'friend_id')
end
```

With a similar statement for the enemies table. Now, my problem is that I want to have a form that the user can use when they sign up, where they can input their information (this is the User object details), and also list their friends and enemies.

Because the user won't have the database id key for their friends or enemies, they'll have to input the users' names. This is fine, though because the name is also a unique key, guaranteed by the validation.

However, if the user types in the name of a friend, I can't join the two if the friend happens to not exist. So, I use a custom validation class that looks something like this:

```
class FriendValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(object)
    #lookup user and throw error if not found.
  end
end
```

which will access the variable (object.friends) and (object.enemies)

With something similar for enemies. So therefore, above my has_and_belongs_to_many statements, I have lines that say:

```
attr_accessor :friends, :enemies #these are attrs because they don't exist within the model's db
validates_with FriendValidator
```

When I create the form with erb, I have the standard form_for block

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
```

It seems to me that I can't just stick

```
<%= f.text_area :friends %>
```

because friends isn't actually something that will get passed to the User object, but rather a separate table. (Can I, though? Because the attr_accessor is declared in the user's model class?)

So now, we have my main problem. I have two many-to-many tables with a model to its own model class, and I don't know how to ensure that the validation class will take the two attributes, lookup and throw necessary errors, and then add a row to the join tables using the id of the user, rather than the string inputted. What form fields should I use to pass the input to the right place? Where do I change the controller methods so that the input gets sent to the join table rather than the user object?

This definitely seems like a pretty specific situation, so I can't really find an answer in the Rails documentation, which I've been learning from.

Answer (score 1):

My initial impression of this problem has to do with your associations. To me, a user has_many enemies and has_many friends.

friends belong_to user

enemies belong_to user

Not sure if a many to many relationship makes sense in this case. Maybe that's why you are having such a hard time finding an answer online. Just my two cents.

Comment: But aren't friends and enemies both users in this situation? What if my objective was to find friends of friends? I would need to call all the user's friends and then on those results call all the friends. Could I do that with this association?